# How to add a plus minus sign to a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, unicode

Here my requirement is to assign + and - to a number both at a time to a number in the label as shown in bellow image in c# asp.net!

[image]

Comment: You mean you want [±](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus-minus_sign)?

Comment: @downvoter you are probably dont have _any clue_ about what the question was about. that's the problem with this downvoting mechanism here on SO.

Comment: yes i want that @Sayse

Comment: @RoyiNamir - To be honest I *did* know what he wanted but then i still found it a little confusing .. "assign to a number"

Comment: @Sayse Confusing ? great. comment him to clarify rather then downvote !

Comment: @RoyiNamir Actually if you hover over the downvote arrow, it says "This question does not show any research effort; **it is unclear** or not useful (click again to undo)". Read the it is unclear part. And yes, I **did** downvote.

Comment: (offtopic solution ) - for more costumized signs and placement : create an ascx  like http://jsbin.com/ukuket/2/edit ( only if you need really customized things)

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance What is not clear with that question that you don't understand  ? apparently others did understood it .

Comment: @RoyiNamir That it's quite confusing: I had to read it three times to understand it.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance _I had to read it three times_.... well the answer is on the the `SubString(0)` part. cuz I didnt and most of us - also.

Comment: @Sayse But he did supply a picture. so what's the problem ? oh well , nevermind.

Comment: @Sayse did you read the initial question ? it had both requirement and a picture. what **else** you want?

Comment: @Sayse **but he did supply a picture**. stop being stubborn. and also `++i--` wont compile so if you supplied that solution you'd had many many downvotes.. FYI.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I'm removing most of my comments on this as it isn't fair to OP, you should do the same. The fact that I needed to comment to clarify says that the question was unclear

Comment: @Sayse  go ahead.  i'm not. people need to see and learn from this.( downvoting while the OP asked a perfectly valid question with a requirement and a picture to add clarification).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use unicode character ["PLUS-MINUS SIGN"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b1/index.htm).

Its code point is `(U+00B1)`

Comment: Ah +1 was struggling to find the unicode value!

Comment: I'm giving this a ± 1 ;)

Comment: poorly answered
See the answer below for correction

Answer (score 11):

```
label.Text = "\u00B1"
```

The Unicode character Plus-Minus-Sign has the code 00B1, and the unicode escape sequence in C# is \u followed by 4 hex-digits.

Answer (score 0):

you could add two other labels with an other font size and a Click-Event to count up or down.

```
    private void minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.number.Text = Convert.ToInt32(this.number.Text) - 1 + "";
    }

    private void plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.number.Text = Convert.ToInt32(this.number.Text) + 1 + "";
    }
```

where "number" ist you number label.

Comment: Wouldn't a `NumericUpDown` be more comfortable for this?

Comment: only a short example, ofc is a NumericUpDown exactiy what my example does but with an other "design"

Comment: Alex, the OP doesn't necessarily need to add and subtract 1, its a mathematical notation for where x can be negative or positive. I see the confusion though

Comment: yes, have seen this as other answers came in :P i thought he want somthing to count